# Using Titan DynamoDB on AWS and querying from NodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, titan, gremlin

I've read most of their documentation, looked into TinkerPop. Tried setting up Docker instances, EC2 instances using AWS CloudFormation template they recommended for Titan 1.0.0 but still can't work it out.

I can start the Titan database, connect gremlin to it and make queries etc. but how do I use it from NodeJs. It seems like since they upgraded to 1.0.0 the documentation doesn't explain it very well. Rexster is now gone as far as I'm aware and was replaced by Gremlin Server but I still can't find anything on remotely working with it.

Really tempted to sack it and move over to Neo4j but don't want to be bound to using a single machine, I want the scalability that Titan allows. I've managed to get older versions of Titan working with Rexster but I need to get the new version running.

Can anyone explain what I need to do or if it's perhaps broken? Or just point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gremlin Server is the replacement for Rexster in TinkerPop3, which Titan 1.0 uses. In the Gremlin Server [documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#gremlin-server), you can find a lot more detail on configuration than the Titan docs.

Under `titan-1.0.0-hadoop1/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml`, you can find the configuration settings for the server. Out of the box, it uses WebSockets and a BerkeleyDB backend. You can update those settings to match your set up. For example, here's a [Titan server](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/titan10/titan-dist/src/assembly/static/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml) configuration for [Cassandra](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/titan10/titan-dist/src/assembly/static/conf/gremlin-server/titan-cassandra-es-server.properties) and Elasticsearch. If you are planning to connect to it from a different computer, make sure to update the `host` property.

Start the server with `bin/gremlin-server.sh conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml` then you can connect to it with a remote connection. As described in the TinkerPop docs, you could connect with a Gremlin Console then issue commands to the remote server.

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
gremlin> :> g.V().values('name')
```

For using Node, you can use this [WebSockets Gremlin client](https://github.com/jbmusso/gremlin-javascript). You can find client libraries for other languages on the [TinkerPop homepage](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/#graph-libraries).

Comment: The host property I have is set to `localhost`, surely this is only to tell Gremlin Server which address to bind to? From my understanding even if it's bound to `localhost` I should be able to use the machine's public IP to access Titan on it's port? One thing I was getting when trying that was a "Server did not respond in a timely manner" (trying to connect to EC2 from local), even connecting from the same EC2 instance to the gremlin server but using a public IP in `remote.yaml` didn't work - same timeout error on query

Comment: Did you set the public IP in both the `gremlin-server.yaml` and the `remote.yaml`? You could set `host=0.0.0.0` in the `gremlin-server.yaml` so it can accept connections to any interface.

Comment: I didn't actually, I'll try that and let you know. Thanks Jason

Comment: You my friend are a life saver!! Thanks a lot Jason!